# Хранение поступающих сообщений в приложении

Tags: android

Помогите пожалуйста выбрать сторону, в которую нужно копать.

Есть приложение, в которое в будущем, будут поступать какие либо новостные сообщения, различным объемом текста.

Суть в том, что пока не гуру в этой области, я не могу придумать как хранить эти самые сообщения, была мысль хранить в БД, но не знаю, целесообразно ли это, и рекомендуется ли это вообще.

Пытался найти какие либо статьи, и пока что безуспешно.
Подскажите куда капнуть. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если данных не очень много (несколько десятков мегабайт), то храните в базе - самое оптимальное. Если же к примеру нужно хранить список статей, которых будет много, то сами статьи храним в отдельных файлах, а id, заголовок статьи, ключевые слова и имя файла - в базе.

Как хранить в базе и как с ней работать - начните с 33-34 урока [здесь](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html).

А вот как именно разложить материал по таблицам - это тема отдельного вопроса, когда будет понятно, что там будет храниться.

Comment: Спасибо, не думал о варианте хранить только "тэги" сообщения в бд.

Сразу попутный вопрос, не попадалось ли Вам русс\англ статьи, по поводу Отправки сообщений в приложения пользователям?

Comment: может [пуш](http://habrahabr.ru/post/116106/) подойдет? Правда c2dm считается устаревшим и рекомендуется использовать [gcm](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).